# Why does FourierSequenceTransform of Cosine result in amplitude of 1/2?

Tags: fourier-analysis, scaling

Can anyone explain why my results with `FourierSequenceTransform` differ from the values in a table in my textbook?

The definition of Discrete-Time Fourier Transform (DTFT) in my textbook matches up with the default `FourierParameters` of the `FourierSequenceTransform` function, but I added it explicitly to be sure.

My textbook states that the DTFT of Cos(n) will result in a series of impulses (Dirac-Delta functions) with amplitude $\pi$. However, when I run the following code, I get an amplitude of 1/2.

The definition in my textbook is

$$X(e^{j\omega})=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(n) e^{-j\omega n} d\omega $$

```
FourierSequenceTransform[Cos[n], n, w, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]

1/2 (DiracComb[(-1 + w)/(2 Pi)] + DiracComb[(1 + w)/(2 Pi)])
```

Comment: This output is correct since $\delta(a x) = \delta(x)/a$ in the sense of distributions.